# What could cause a sleeping session to have an open transaction?

Tags: sql-server, performance, query-performance, sql-server-2014

For one of our SQL servers there has been a proc which creates a blocking mess:

That stored proc completes under a sec most of the times but somehow is leaving transaction open. What i see from sp_whoisactive is status = sleeping and open tran 1 for duration of approx 5-6 minutes. In this duration heaving blocking chain shows up.

This SP do not have any transaction like BEGIN and END TRAN. It does some basic select col,col2,col3.... into #temptables from table1 inner join table 2 ... and then select from that #temptable

While we are checking from app why there could be a transaction left open, i was reading in such scenarios to use XACT ABORT ON in SP itself. But when there is no transaction involved how XACT ABORT setting will help in  this case?

Please advise

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scenarios that may explain these symptoms include:

1. The application code has started a transaction and not committed
2. The application `SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON`
3. The stored procedure includes `SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON`

This DMV query will help troubleshooting. The [transaction name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-tran-active-transactions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) value will be "implicit_transaction" if started implicitly. Other possible values include "user_transaction", "DTC Transaction", or a user-specified transaction name. A "user_transaction" value (with no explict proc transaction) indicates the transaction must have been started on the client side and not committed. A value of "DTC Transaction" indicates a distributed transaction, also indicating an  issue with transaction management on the app side.

```
SELECT
      session_tran.session_id
    , active_tran.name 
FROM sys.dm_tran_session_transactions AS session_tran
INNER JOIN sys.dm_tran_active_transactions AS active_tran ON session_tran.transaction_id = active_tran.transaction_id;
```

It is a good practice to include `SET XACT_ABORT ON` in stored procedures with explict transactions to ensure transactions are rolled back, especially following a client timeout. That probably won't help here since your proc has no explict transaction, unless the proc happens to raise an error and rollback the erroneous transaction as result.

Comment: Thanks Dan, Will a TRY/CATCH help here to implement if abort setting makes not much sense

Comment: You could include a `CATCH` block like `IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK; THROW;`, with or without `SET XACT_ABORT ON;`, to rollback a transaction even if not start by the proc. However, that will not help unless an errors occurs during execution. Also, the `CATCH` block will not be executed if the client cancels the query due to a timeout.

Comment: thanks. Is there a way to query from SQL server if store procs coming from app are using which option of implicit transaction oN or off

Comment: @BeginnerDBA, I added a query to my answer that should help.

Comment: great this is great, can we join another dmv to actually see a query next to SPID which i showing IMPLICIT. I see some of them showing up

Comment: @BeginnerDBA, to get the last batch executed, add `input_buffer.event_info` to the column list and this to the end of the query: `OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_input_buffer(session_tran.session_id, NULL) AS input_buffer`

Comment: Thanks i am 90% of time seeing as user_transactions and just couple of procs with implicit. Have notified app team and they are surprised as they are not sending from app and neither in proc as implicit on. I appreciate all your great help here. Do you think user_transaction will contribute to sleeping as well, i can open second question if thats needed

Comment: The transactions (user or implicit) are not contributing to sleeping connections. An uncommitted transaction on a long inactive (sleeping) connection indicates a problem with transaction management. I suggest you see if you can repro the symptoms in a test environment, capturing activity with a trace of sql_transaction, and begin_tran_completed events. A begin_tran_completed indicates an API-initiated transaction. A sql_transaction event indicates a T-SQL-initiated transaction transaction, will also indicate if it's implicit or user.